# extract substring after first number

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator, vbscript

Suppose I have a field titled **NAME1**.

Examples of what is in the field appear like this:

Fox Lake 1
WABASCA 166
TSU TUE 196G
YELLOW QUILL I.R. 90-8
POUNDMAKER INDIAN RESERVE NO. 114-17
CROSS LAKE 19X02
BEARDY'S & OKEMASIS I.R. 96 & 97A

How using python or vb script would I extract a string only after the first digit into a new field titled **Name_Num**?

Basically, the Name_Num field would have to appear like this:

1
166
196G
90-8
114-17
19X02
96 & 97A

Mind you, I need the letter attached to the numbers. I can't just extract digits only. But anything before the first number must go. The numbers vary in character length but always appear at the end of my string.

I rarely use python and am not familiar with when something goes into the pre-code block or doesn't.

These are the results after inputting the first reply which looked great in my opinion but didn't work unfortunately.

[image: results after first comment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for positive numbers, as it looks like you are extracting address elements.

Run a field calculate on Name_Num field.

Put this in the pre-logic Script Code (make sure Parser is Python):

```
def extract_from_number_to_end(input_string):
    output = input_string # return input if no number found
    for char in input_string:
        if char.isdigit():
            pos = input_string.find(char)
            output = input_string[pos:]
            break #stop as we have found the first number
    return output
```

And call it in the Name_Num = part like:

```
extract_from_number_to_end(!MyField!)
```

It defaults to returning the original string if no number is found.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! it didn't work unfortunately, but see image attached to original post. Does that help?

Comment: Whoops, totally my fault, I forgot to update the calling code to match the name of the def. Have updated my answer, try that.

Comment: Actually, i previously wrote a comment saying it didn't work again. BUT IT DID!!! Only for half the number of records and I don't know why. Results say that there a row containing a bad value. Is there any way to locate this bad value row?

Comment: Nevermind I realized that one of the entries was too long to fit the 50 char limit, which halted the process. You are a genius. THANK YOU.

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help!